# How to change automatically installed package to intentionally intalled?

Tags: apt, aptitude

I'm using Debian Jessie. I'm installing some software Z from source. Installation instructions inform that it depends on Debian package X. I checked in aptitude and I have this package installed, but it is marked as automatically installed (`iA`).

So if some day I remove package Y that caused package X to be installed my software Z will stop to work. So my question is, how can I change flags of package from `iA` to `i`. Preferably using aptitude in non-interactive mode. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `apt-mark` for that. From it's manpage:

```
   auto
       auto is used to mark a package as being automatically installed, which will cause
       the package to be removed when no more manually installed packages depend on this
       package.

   manual
       manual is used to mark a package as being manually installed, which will prevent the 
       package from being automatically removed if no other packages depend on it.
```

In you case you should mark it as `manual`. Use a command like this:

```
apt-mark manual <package-name>
```

Comment: `aptitude unmarkauto` works too.

Comment: You can also add a user-tag to a package so that you know why it's needed: `aptitude add-user-tag "this is a tag" packagename`. This can be seen with `aptitude show packagename` or in interactive mode when hitting enter while the package is highlighted.